# get data by duration (daily, weekly, monthly) in neo4j CQL

Tags: neo4j, cypher

New to neo4j.
My neo4j relationships look something like....

```
(p:Person{
    name:"XYZ",
    joinDate:'date_ in_datetime_format'
})
 -[:PART_OF]-> 
(c:Club {name:"ABC"})
```

I want to produce a list of members for durations like daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly. So if duration is Daily, I want to get 'no. of people added' for all days along with a index (list of  {ratio, index}). Same goes for weekly, monthly and so on...
I want to write different queries for different duration cases.
I know how to count  all schemes and members and hot get the cases, the thing I am getting stuck at counting members added in a duration like daily, weekly, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Cypher has an automatic groupBy where the key on the left is the aggregation key and the rest is automatically grouped by that key.

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/

So if you return the day of the Person `joinDate` property and a count(*) it will do what you're looking for.

For months you return the month, for quarters you return the quarters. You can check here about instant values possible https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-accessing-components-temporal-instants

For daily :

```
(p:Person{
    name:"XYZ",
    joinDate:'date_ in_datetime_format'
})
 -[:PART_OF]-> 
(c:Club {name:"ABC"})
RETURN p.joinDate.year + '-' + p.joinDate.month + '-' p.joinDate.day AS window, count(*) AS count
```

For monthly :

```
(p:Person{
    name:"XYZ",
    joinDate:'date_ in_datetime_format'
})
 -[:PART_OF]-> 
(c:Club {name:"ABC"})
RETURN p.joinDate.year + '-' + p.joinDate.month AS window, count(*) AS count
```

For quarterly :

```
(p:Person{
    name:"XYZ",
    joinDate:'date_ in_datetime_format'
})
 -[:PART_OF]-> 
(c:Club {name:"ABC"})
RETURN p.joinDate.year + '-' p.joinDate.quarter AS window, count(*) AS count
```

For yearly :

```
(p:Person{
    name:"XYZ",
    joinDate:'date_ in_datetime_format'
})
 -[:PART_OF]-> 
(c:Club {name:"ABC"})
RETURN p.joinDate.year AS window, count(*) AS count
```

Comment: HOw should I approach it if I want the  count to be cumulative, lets say if on  day 1 members added were 5, and day two member added were 8, then on day 2 i want to show the cumulative count, basically total members that exist on that day